# determine if object in the same direction or not android

Tags: android, geolocation, gps, compass-geolocation

I want to develop an app that, at first, submit an object location "With Direction" so that when moving again in this street in later time "in the same direction" I can detect that and tell the user you are in the same direction of that object and you are xyz meters far.

object location and distance will be detected using the location provider service weather it is GPS or another one.

my problem now is the direction , how to submit object direction so that later I can know that i'm in the same direction of the street.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is your problem obtaining the direction? If so: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html -> read on getOrientation(). If the problem is storing the direction then just read on SQLite databases in Android. Store it in db, then compare current location and direction to the ones in db

Comment: my problem is obtaining the direction with relation to the street direction. what does this obtained orientation refer to ? in relation to what ? what if a point x is in the same direction in the North and another one in same direction in the South ?

Comment: So basically you don't need an accurate direction (like with 360 degrees) but rather information if user is pointing to this end of the street or the opposite, right? The only problem I can think of here is to get the coordinates of those two opposite ends of the street. Because the math (line between two geopoints) is rather simple. Obtaining user direction in relation to this line too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find direction between two points you can use one of the following:

1-If using Location objects:

```
Location initialPoint = new Location("");
initialPoint.setLatitude(initialLatitude);
initialPoint.setLongitude(initialLongitude);

Location finalPoint = new Location("");
finalPoint .setLatitude(finalLatitude);
finalPoint .setLongitude(finalLongitude);

float direction = initialPoint.bearingTo(finalPoint);
```

2-Using static Location method

```
private float results2[] = new float[2];
Location.distanceBetween(initialLatitude, initialLongitude, finalLatitude, finalLongitude, results);
float direction = reasults[1];
```

Regards

Comment: what does this obtained direction refer to ? in relation to what ?
what if a point x is in the same direction in the North and another one in same direction in the South ?

Comment: As the name from the variables suggest, it returns de direction from the initial point to the final point. From the documentation: "Returns the approximate initial bearing in degrees East of true North when traveling along the shortest path between this location and the given location. The shortest path is defined using the WGS84 ellipsoid. Locations that are (nearly) antipodal may produce meaningless results."